# Using sed to copy a string of x-number of characters from a specific line

Tags: sed

I am trying to use sed in order to copy partial strings from a log file.

When I wanted to copy a whole line, I used:

for file in `ls Dir/logs/*NN*`

do

```
   sed -n 3,3p $file >> log_NN.csv
```

done

Is there a similar command that will take only part of a string, in a certain location of that line?

For example I have in line 22 of the log the following string, and I want to copy the first number to another file, then the 2nd number to a file, etc...:

step - loss: 0.6844 - acc: 0.6294 - val_loss: 0.5905

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==22 { print $4 >> file1;print $7 >> file2; print $10 >> file3 }' Dir/logs/*NN*
```

Awk would be a better candidate for this. Process all the files at once and then when the File number record (FNR - the line in each file) is 22, append the 4th space delimited field to file1, the seventh to file2 and then 10th to file3.

Comment: Thanks! Apologies, but since I am new to awk, how do I implement a string wildcard in the file name? I mean: print $4 >> file1, where file 1 is in my script log_nn_${i}.csv ? it doesn't seem to run because of the wildcard :/

Comment: The same as you would normally e.g. the way you would for ls

Comment: thanks! it worked! not sure why it gave me syntax error using directly the wildcard in the file name, probably I am missing something, but I managed to bypass it by implementing your suggestion in the same loop like this: awk 'FNR==22 { print $4 ;print $7; print $10 }' Dir/logs/*NN* > file_tmp ; cat file_tmp >> log_nn_${i}.csv   and for some reason this did work. In any case - thank u so much!

Comment: Great!!! If the solution has helped you meet your objective, please up vote and accept the answer.